# Google App Engine - Terminal Scripts

Tags: google-app-engine, import, terminal

I'm trying to run some of my python scripts from the terminal (Mac OS) and I'm getting import errors.
For example, if I try to import main, I get the following:

```
ImportError: No module named webapp2
```

If I try to import a model script, I get the following:

```
ImportError: No module named yaml
```

My .bash_profile has this PYTHONPATH setting -

```
export GAE="/usr/local/google_appengine"
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:$GAE:$GAE/lib/django_1_4:$GAE/lib/:$GAE/lib/yaml"
```

I've also tried this approach:

```
import os
import sys

DIR_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
# ...

EXTRA_PATHS = [
          DIR_PATH,
          os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'antlr3'),
          os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'django'),
          os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'fancy_urllib'),
          os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'ipaddr'),
          os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'webob'),
          os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'yaml', 'lib'),
]
# ...
sys.path = EXTRA_PATHS + sys.path
```

And then I import that script before trying to import other GAE scripts and it still doesn't work. Anybody have their terminal all setup to run their GAE scripts? If so, how'd you do it/what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Common problem, very frustrating for me first time. If you start to chase all the various imports yourself, you'll wind up with a frakenstein path that seems to have no logic. Then I finally read how GAE SDK does it itself. Try this at the top of your file after you add GAE to your `PYTHONPATH`:

```
import dev_appserver
dev_appserver.fix_sys_path()
```

Good luck!